# Get one column table when doing localization

Tags: mysql, normalization, localization

I have got only one column for a table when i create two localized tables. Code as bellow.

```
-- Month
CREATE TABLE `month` (
  `id` INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
);

-- Month Localized
CREATE TABLE `month_loc` (
  `month_id'    INT NOT NULL,
  `name`        VARCHAR(200)    NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(500)    NOT NULL,
  `lang_id`     INT NOT NULL
);
```

`month_loc.month_id` is the foreign key.

Month table holds only the primary key. Other all fields should be localized. Is this table structure correct ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that each month is universally identified by number (1 is January, 2 is February, etc.), it is useless to have a table that store the first twelve numbers, so you could have a single table, with the following attributes:

```
CREATE TABLE month_loc (
  month_number    INT NOT NULL,
  name            VARCHAR(200)    NOT NULL,
  description     VARCHAR(500)    NOT NULL,
  lang_id         INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(lang_id,month_number)
);
```

You could use this table to find efficiently a certain month in a certain language.